# Which of DC's mortals can survive Darkseid's Omega Beam?

Tags: dc

I always thought that Darkseid's Omega Beam can disintegrate anything. But, I just discovered that it didn't disintegrate Superman.

Other than Superman, how many DC's mortals have survived Darkseid's Omega Beam, or can survive Darkseid's Omega Beam?

Answer (score 3):

Supergirl does, several times, in *Superman/Batman: Apocalypse*.